# How to use a variable that has $ sign in popup window url ?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a hyperlink that suppose to popup.Problem is that if url of popup window has $ sign on it the window never pops up .I have included two fiddle demo one without $ which works and one with $ that dont work. Could any one help me to fix the one that has $ sign as popup window url?

variable that has $ sign:

```
&variable1=$.mydef1('season_one_display')&variable2=$.mydef2('season_two_display')
```

full code:

```
 var itemName = 'Test'
    var itemName2 = 'popup'
    var siteContents2 = "<li>"
       +"<iframe src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe><br>"
       +"<div class='details'>"
       +"<div class='title'>"
       +"<a href='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' target=\"_blank\"'>"+itemName+"</a><br>"
    +"<a href=\"javascript:window.open('http://awebsite.com/static/flash/ok1234567890123445.swf?itemid="+itemName+"&address=bsite.com&language=http://bsite.com/xml/viewer.xml&ok=1&pr=login_required_true_if_loggedin&sa=0&id=user15&jg=$.mydef&dp=$.mydef2&js=registration_required&dom=bsite.com&pn=bsiteak&variable1=$.mydef1('season_one_display')&variable2=$.mydef2('season_two_display')' , 'yourWindowName' , 'width=200,height=150')\">"+itemName2+"</a>" 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents2;

    <ul id="myDiv"></ul>
```

working fiddle demo(wihtout $):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vpwxy/

Not working fiddle demo(with $):

http://jsfiddle.net/yXvAu/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `'` inside each other, in the URL parameter of window.open. It's not the dollar sign ($) that's causing you problems.

```
<a href=\"javascript:window.open('http://awe.....&variable1=$.mydef1('se.....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so what should i do in order to make it popup?

Comment: You can replace the innermost ticks with `&quot;`